# set enforce-gtid-consistency back to false

Tags: google-cloud-sql

anyone has the experience that cloudsql replication change this parameter to true, which doesn't allow multiple statement in a transaction, or create temp table.
how do I change it back to false in cloudsql?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

H., this is Danny from CloudSQL. We switched to use GTID for replication which ensures no data loss during replica creation or failover. It's going to be default after MySQL 5.7. With GTID enabled, the flag "enforce-gtid-consistency" has to be set. When enabled, this option enforces GTID consistency by allowing execution of only those statements that can be logged in a transactionally safe manner. It follows that the operations listed here cannot be used with this option:
 1. CREATE TABLE ... SELECT statements
 2. CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE statements inside transactions
 3. Transactions or statements that update both transactional and nontransactional tables.

If you can share your query, I can help you find a walk-around to separate the temp table from multiple statement transaction. Sorry about the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but its with magento 2.  I cannot easily change how they do their queries so the only option to me was to build a msql server in compute engine.

Comment: This is possible by disabling "binary log" on the CloudSQL server. You will not be able to do replication. I have CloudSQL working with Magento 2.

Comment: @david For anyone coming by today, August 2019 or later, disabling binary logs do not disable GTID consistency. It is permanently on.

Answer (score 0):

this is very sad, CREATE TABLE ...  SELECT is not an unusual feature to just discard